# Bootloop issue and can't go to recovery mode

Tags: boot-loop, bootloader, asus-zenfone-3

I am using Asus Zenfone 3 ZE552KL, it got hang and then i tried to restart the phone but it get stucked in, Also I can't get in to recovery using standard method. Generally I keep USB debugging mode off that's why my device not listed in `adb devices` list but, i can go into CSC Fastboot mode.
[image: fastbootmod]

Text in the image.
csc fastboot mode!!! long time press power button to restart
I tried below solutions

1. Used [Asus Flash tool](https://www.asusflashtool.com/) as per its help doc the process takes 10 to 15min but i wait around more than 2 hours it shows "Uploading OS Version"
2. I downloaded [Firmware zip file](https://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone-3-ZE552KL/HelpDesk_BIOS/) from asus official site, but in zip file only `boot.img` is present other two requried files are missing `recovery.img` and `fastboot.img`

[image: Firware Folder]

Kindly suggest me some workaround.

Comment: Hi @alecxs, Thanks for your answer. Just want to know from where I can get `twrp-3.2.3-zenfone3-20180806.img` file

Comment: got it, tried your method and getting this error `Sending 'boot.img' (21090 KB)                      FAILED (Write to device failed (Unknown error))"`

Comment: please try `flashall_AFT.cmd` it may work with locked bootloader (link see answer below)

Comment: @alecxs i tried flashall_AFT.cmd method, and got this error "FAILED (remote: failed to write partition)". I think need to set some permissions to write data, is it so?

Comment: then you are left with EDL mode

Comment: the device's USB debugging mode is off.

Comment: EDL mode is qualcomm **E**mergency **D**own**L**oad Mode and doesn't require adb usb-debugging, oem unlocking or fastboot. instead it requires deep flash cable and factory loader (firehose programmer)

Answer (score 2):

The *Asus Zenfone Flash Tool* is no official Software, furthermore it looks like this tool is using *fastboot* (which usually works on previously unlocked bootloader only)

---

for `fastboot.exe` download [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) and open `cmd.exe`. navigate to `platform-tools` folder with `cd` now you can type

```
fastboot reboot
```

if bootloader is already unlocked, you can also wipe *cache* partition and see if this fixes your boot problem

```
fastboot format:ext4 cache
```

---

you can also boot into *recovery* from fastboot and then install firmware *update.zip*. this should even work from [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3742765) as long as you don't flash recovery.
do **NOT** allow modifications of system. just wipe cache partition. try to reboot into system from menu. if still not booting, install firmware update.zip

```
fastboot boot C:\platform-tools\twrp-3.2.3-zenfone3-20180806.img
```

---

for **locked bootloader** you can download *Factory_Phone-userdebug.raw* emmc image which contains GPT partition table and all partitions. (from linux it is possible to loop-mount this image with *kpartx*  and split into partitions, but this is out of scope)

**WARNING: all data lost**
this will flash the entire device, be aware this deletes all your personal data. make sure this is the right phone model.
download [CSC_ZE552KL_13_13_1_36_M2_6_7_P7_userdebug.zip](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3738811).
it seems no flash tool is needed, it is maybe working from fastboot directly.
connect usb cable in fastboot mode and just run `flashall_AFT.cmd`

---

**Qualcomm Devices** usually can be flashed from *EDL mode* with *QPST*.
found a site with some [Qualcomm EDL Programmers](https://firmwarego.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=folder&id=2288) <s>maybe one of this works for your device

[Qualcomm_Factory_Loader_MSM8953_Lenovo.mbn](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xotSfiI4sfhC3QwAkOKe3nDbQpwMJWdu)

[Qualcomm_Factory_Loader_MSM8953_Xiaomi.mbn](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14aUzOkW0v0EatU28OD-5n6c6c3K53xpH)

[Qualcomm_Factory_Loader_MSM8953_Xiaomi_2nd.mbn](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U8h6pHE0q65irx9m82-MaX8zhjcGQsy0)</s>

for **EDL mode** install [Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 Driver](https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-6-2019/how-to/qdloader-brick-t3980165)

for *EDL mode* you need to find Test Point

[image: Redmi-Note-4]

[image: Redmi-5-Plus]

---

**The following is just an example to illustrate the process and not valid instructions**

For further documentation refer to [alephsecurity](https://github.com/alephsecurity/firehorse/blob/master/README.md) there you can learn how to flash devinfo which unlocks bootloader and gives availbilitiy to flash custom recovery TWRP

basically you need the following files (most of them are included in [QPST](https://androidmtk.com/use-qpst-flash-tool))

```
fh_loader.exe
QSaharaServer.exe
prog_emmc_firehose_8953.mbn
rawprogram0.xml  
patch0.xml
```

the xml file has instructions for flashing partition, for example TWRP (not the right size/offset)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
 <program SECTOR_SIZE_IN_BYTES="512" file_sector_offset="0" filename="recovery.img" label="recovery" num_partition_sectors="131072" physical_partition_number="0" size_in_KB="65536.0" sparse="false" start_byte_hex="0x1c200000" start_sector="921600" />
</data>
```

QSaharaServer.exe is used to initialize firehose with on the already to COM port connected device in EDL mode

```
QSaharaServer.exe -p \\.\COM10 -s 13:prog_emmc_firehose_8953.mbn -b tmp\"
```

fh_loader.exe is responsible for flashing the instructions from xml file

```
fh_loader.exe --search_path=tmp --port=\\.\COM10 --sendxml=twrp.xml"
```

Comment: search for collections like [romprovider.com](https://romprovider.com/download-prog_emmc_firehose-qcom-phone-cpus), [firmware27.com](https://www.firmware27.com/2017/06/collectionprog-emmc-firehose-prog-ufs.html), [leakite.com](https://www.leakite.com/collection-qualcomm-emmc-programmer-files), github.com [1](https://github.com/programmer-collection), [2](https://github.com/bkerler/Loaders), [tuserhp.com](https://www.tuserhp.com/2018/02/prog-emmc-firehose-ufs-firehose.html), [firmwarego.com](https://firmwarego.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=folder&id=2288)

Comment: found [prog_emmc_firehose_8953_ddr.mbn](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bricked-asus-ze552kl-dead-qualcomm-hs-usb-qdloader-9008.3603643/page-4#post-84752847) (chinese post)