# Android OnePlus 3T stuck on boot logo, how can i recover data?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot-loop, bootloader-lock, side-loading

My OnePlus 3T recently got a bootloop issue (stuck on boot logo).

Bootloader locked, stock ROM and unrooted device.

How can I recover my data?

I've already tried wipe data and reset system setting from recovery mode on my phone.

I have a pc with Windows os and another with Ubuntu os, if this can help.

On Windows i can see "Qualcomm HS-USB QDLoader 9008 (COM3)" on "PORT(com and lpt)" menu under "Device Manager".

I read many forums, but i find only this 2 solutions, that doesn't work for me:

1- Use an app on Windows called Android Data Recovery, but to use that i need to have USBDebugging setted on and i think i don't have. To do that you need your phone on and setting developer option enabled but i can't because stuck on boot logo.

2- Install a custom recovery to get data from phone storage. To get a custome revovery you have to unlock bootloader but i can't because to unlock bootloader i need to erase my memory.

My priority is get data from phone, if anyone can help or have any suggestion is really appriciated.

Ps: I find a way to connect phone and pc on Windows with USB cable. Using from Windows terminal the command ADB devices, it returns that my phone on "sideload" mode. I read there is a command "abd sideload file.zip" that flash your rom with file.zip, but i don't understand if this operation delete your data.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224131

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224369

Answer (score 0):

there is a 3rd way for locked bootloader without erasing userdata, but it all depends on the qualcomm factory loader firehose programmer which is special for each model

these are expert tools for EDL mode to dump partitions or install TWRP from where you should be able to decrypt

https://github.com/alephsecurity/firehorse

https://github.com/bkerler/edl

but i can't guide you i have no experience