# cant flash Lenovo Tab M10 TB-X605L LTE with Android 8

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, linux, 8.1-oreo, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Tab M10 TB-X605L LTE that I would like to give to my grandfather with Teamviewer Host installed to accept incoming calls because he is unable to do so. We want to give him the opportunity to videocall with family members during the corona confinement.

Unfortunately the Teamviewer Host app is giving issues on Android 9 and needs to be flashed to Android 8 for it to work.

I found this helpful post by BogisW and followed the steps he described:
[Cannot flash Qualcomm with Stock Image (Lenovo Tab M10 TB-X605L LTE, Android 8 Oreo)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224369/cannot-flash-qualcomm-with-stock-image-lenovo-tab-m10-tb-x605l-lte-android-8-o)

I'm running into issues when putting in the flash command:

```
./qdl --debug --storage emmc --include 'TB-X605L_USER_S000020_20180921_Q00020_ROW' 'TB-X605L_USER_S000020_20180921_Q00020_ROW/prog_emmc_firehose_8953_ddr.mbn' 'TB-X605L_USER_S000020_20180921_Q00020_ROW/rawprogram_unsparse.xml' '/TB-X605L_USER_S000020_20180921_Q00020_ROW/patch0.xml'
```

these are the errors i get back:

```
[PATCH] failed to parse /TB-X605L_USER_S000020_20180921_Q00020_ROW/rawprogram_unsparse.xml
qdl: failed to detect file type of /TB-X605L_USER_S000020_20180921_Q00020_ROW/rawprogram_unsparse.xml
```

```
[PATCH] failed to parse /TB-X605L_USER_S000020_20180921_Q00020_ROW/patch0.xml
qdl: failed to detect file type of /TB-X605L_USER_S000020_20180921_Q00020_ROW/patch0.xml
```

I have no TWRP installed and doing this from a Ubuntu linux machine.
It seems to me the issue could be with the path to the unzipped firmware but i don't know where to place them and don't understand the `--storage emmc`... should they be placed on a SD card? should i mount it in any way?

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what to do here, i'm getting stuck and i'm just trying to get this to work and have the tablet shipped to my grandfather to make some videocalls.
Thanks!!

Comment: please read the error message it is very clear: patch0.xml does not exist (wrong path), you must specify right path on PC. also the instructions are very clear: *'<path to the unzipped firmware files>/patch0.xml'*

Comment: Thanks i got it working with removing the forward slash.