# Unable to do factory reset on my vivo mobile without password

Tags: factory-reset

My mobile model is **vivo y95**. I forgot my new pattern which i have changed recently and im unable to unlock my mobile. So i tried to do factory reset on my mobile.

But when i click on **Wipe data** option it is asking pattern again.

Please let me know any option to unlock my phone (With factory reset also fine).

Comment: https://www.gsmsmall.com/2019/10/reset-pattern-vivo-y91y95-qualcomm.html

Comment: @alecxs Is it possible to do it with Ubuntu system?

Comment: yes and no. not with QPST, but with other tools https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224369

Comment: `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot` I cant download android adb tool also in my system Its showing 404 error

Comment: install apt-transport-https [apt-get fails: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/263801) or download platform-tools from google https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads

Comment: @alecxs from the above link you sent me in first comment is not downloading tools properly.. Im getting only vlc files from the website

Comment: Please give me official link where i can get vivo reset pattern tools.. Im stuck with this since 3 days

Comment: there is no official reset pattern tool, the link is just instruction how to format userdata partition. you need to extract `prog_emmc_firehose_8937_ddr.mbn` from Split / [QFIL Firmware](https://www.firmware27.com/2018/10/firmware-vivo-1807-y91-y95.html)

Comment: `prog_emmc_firehose_8937_ddr.mbn` ? Where i can get it?