# TWRP Advanced Wipe Soft Bricked?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode

Messed around with my Moto G7 Plus Lake on Lineage 17.1 & ended up with TWRP on partition B & Lineage Recovery on Partition A, no matter my inexpert fumblings. I somewhat unfortunately carried out an advanced wipe on A/B with TWRP & now recovery is unresponsive over ADB or touch. I assume device is toast?

So is there any procedure to rectify, or do I need pop to Shenzhen market & solder new ROM?

Comment: Boot to bootloader and use fastboot (on Windows separate drivers required) to directly boot TWRP from an image on your PC.

Comment: It says waiting for any device.

Comment: you probably wiped dtbo which isn't necessary, only wipe (impact from harmless to worst): cache, (wipe) data, (format) userdata, system, vendor (regardless of how many partitions wipeable from TWRP)

Comment: flash with QPST in EDL mode

Comment: Can this be done under Linux?

Comment: @alecxs thx for gifting that tip!

Comment: yes there is tool for linux https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224369