# Flashing stockrom on a "Lenovo Tab4 8 Plus" in EDL Mode

Tags: rom-flashing

I have tried to install TWRP and LineageOS on my "lenovo Tab4 8 Plus" and it didn't go well.
Now I have a broken device... no function, only connected with PC and its a Qualcomm Device in a Diagnosis Mode, or when I change the Driver its Qualcomm HS-USB Qloader 9008. How ever I change the driver or try all possible tools like MiFlash, QFil or Lenovo Rescue and Smart Assistant it doesn't all help and no flashing possible. Do guys have any Idea what could be wrong?

I thank you all.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224369

Comment: I tried exactly thsát with Linux... problem is I have this Case:
Option 2: You cannot access your Android system (almost bricked)
I can't boot in fastboot cause I have only EDL mode and bye the way I don't get that short vibration... I have tried all the stuff I found and this one is my last hope cause Linux and it could be the same problem. How do I get in fastboot mode to upload the twrp.img File with a device in EDL mode?

Thanks for helping me out of this dillema...

Comment: you don't need fastboot or TWRP if your device is already in EDL mode just skip to *Flash your device*

Comment: adb reboot edl
error: no devices/emulators found

Comment: Thanks again. I think my problme is, that the device is not in EDL mode, it is in a diagnostic mode. All I try to get in EDL mode doens't work. As I know its Volume Up and connect Cable...

Comment: in that case you need to figure out [test point](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=TB-8704X+test+point+edl) method. watch on yt how to open your device without damaging display. once it's open search for golden dots on platine. touch with fingers while connecting usb-cable (sometimes that's enough)

Comment: or search for EDL in [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3664407&page=66) support thread (page 49: *'turn the device completely off. Press both volume buttons at the same time (even if it's a rocker, it'll work), and only then plug in the USB cable'*)

Comment: Hi everyone. I wish you guys first of all best health :)
Unfortunatly I couldn't get this device in EDL mode via buttons... I had to open it... but I do not see or know which pins I have to connect... any ideas wich "test points"?
Would it maybe work when I buy a special USB kabel?

Comment: you can try DIY cable http://xiaomitips.com/guide/miui-deep-flash-engineering-cable-solution-to-non-edl-device

Comment: also ask in forums [gsmdevelopers.com](https://forum.gsmdevelopers.com/lenovo-firmware-unified/54056-lenovo-tab-4-8-plus-tb-8704x-firmware.html) or [gsmhosting.com](https://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/13226099-post2.html) or the above [xda-developers.com](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3664407) and search for telegram support