# How to install standard european stock firmware on Motorola G 5G XT2113-3?

Tags: stock-android, motorola

I own a Motorola G 5G XT2113-3 that is on the "timit" software channel (TIM Italy retailer). In the recovery functionality of the LMSA tool, I noticed that by default it downloads the software / firmware in the European retail version (reteu software channel). It's correct? If I proceed, do I run any risks? Do you know the difference between this two channels? And what is the best way to install the standard european stock firmware? (LMSA, RSD or other tools).

Because I would prefer to have a phone with regular updates and with the software indipendent from the brand.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot flash Qualcomm with Stock Image (Lenovo Tab M10 TB-X605L LTE, Android 8 Oreo)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224369/cannot-flash-qualcomm-with-stock-image-lenovo-tab-m10-tb-x605l-lte-android-8-o)

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/download-motorola-stock-rom-for-all-models

Comment: If you unlock bootloader you can flash anything\* from fastboot mode (\*except for bootloader which is downgrade protected). I wouldn't say it's the best way but it's "safest" method (unlocked bootloader is backdoor for data recovery). But LSMA is the official way and there is no risk flashing retail. I doubt there is any difference other than branding, you will receive updates (if any). I think you are already on the right track and don't need help. You can self-answer question with tutorial for LSMA with screenshots maybe