# How to access my android phones data with only fastboot mode access and no developer options enabled and no access to recovery options?

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, fastboot, developer-options

I have an Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1 device. Few hours back, it shutdown suddenly and i cannot reboot it. What all i tried are:

1) When i try to Restart, it shuts down after showing asus logo.
2) When i try to access Recovery Mode by pressing Volume Down and Power Button, it shuts down after showing asus logo.Hence cache cannot be cleared
3) I can Access CSC FASTBOOT MODE. But no Developer options enabled.

Can someone help me on how i can get my datas back in this situation? all tutorials on web says my issue will be due to corrupt files. I am ready to factory reset my device. But my data is precious. Confidential Office files have to be retrieved. Any ways?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224131

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HDMuzrNvN0

Comment: @alecxs: Thanks for the input bro. let me go through those :)