# realme 3 pro stuck at bootloop (boot/recovery) has been destroyed

Tags: adb, rooting

Hi my mobile is in boot loop

fastboot not working i have tried every button but none worked
not connecting to pic / laptop as well
any one have a solution please help

i did flash my stock rom with orangefox recovery. then mobile has no recovery after flashing the rom, but fastboot was connecting to pc.

i followed this [unbrick guide](https://www.ytechb.com/how-to-unbrick-realme-3-fix-bootloop-easy-guide) working fine i perform 8) step did lock bootloader

now its not connecting to pc, booting into fastboot, but when i hold both vol button + power after some time i do hear a noice from pc the sound of connection but not showing in pc that it is connected and i do hear disconnect sound after a minute or so

[image: realme.png]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109077/discussion-on-question-by-najam-realme-3-pro-stuck-at-bootloop-boot-recovery-h).

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224131

Answer (score 0):

The only option is service center bro since u locked the bootloader