# Getting Root Access on Android 6.0.1 in Recovery Mode

Tags: root-access, data-recovery

I am trying to get root access from recovery mode with the Dirty Cow exploit. I have adb access and my device is on Android 6.0.1. When I use VIKIROOT it's stuck at "waiting for reverse connect shell".
I cannot open the clock/alarm app or toggle the bluetooth switch in order to trigger the backdoor. How can I root the device from recovery mode and decrypt the data (I know the passcode) of the device? Thanks.

Comment: Asus Zenfone 3. I am trying to use Dirty Cow as there is no other way that I know. I don't want to unlock the bootloader as it would wipe the data.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224131

Comment: My device doesn't have a programmer and Kingoroot won't work on recovery mode.

Comment: I tried those programmers and they didn't work. A programmer is specific to a device and they need to be signed.

Comment: which one exactly you tried? usually signing is just vendor specific

Comment: I confirm that prog_emmc_firehose_8953_ddr_asus.mbn does not work.

Comment: thx for testing! too bad.. i assume you can't boot android anymore?

Comment: Sadly, I can't. Is there any other way for me to root my device on recovery mode? I can use adb just fine.

Comment: you can wipe cache partition, or install official updates from adb sideload or MicroSD card. nothing more you can do. even chip-off won't work for encrypted device

Comment: not sure about this (it's 9006 DLOAD mode) https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/how-to-backup-qualcomm-phone-root-t3570178

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. Thanks for help anyway.