# My Firmware do not have emmc, raw program and patch file

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, nokia-x

I own a heavily Bricked Nokia X Rm-980. Currently, I am trying to bring it back to life.
It is detected as Qualcomm HS_USB QDLoader 9008 (Com3). After spending some time online, i got a possible solution, flashing it using QFIL. I downloaded the firmware ([LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8IYBLcaLsg_M0JmeEY4QlpDY0k/view)), it didn't have 3 files needed to start the flash process which were raw program XML file, patch file, prog emmc file. I looked up Online for these file specifically, But found nothing.
Do anyone know what should I do

Comment: Generally these files are not available from most manufacturers, and the only way we get them is if they "leak" out somehow, which is rare in most cases... The file you downloaded is likely an upgrade file only to be used on a operational device, which has a different structure and format and is used by either tools built into the existing OS, or things like fastboot (part of the core of Android). \

Comment: So, is there any other way to get it to life?

Comment: https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_us/support (adjust for your region/country) and click Repair and Replacement... Unfortunately, for most devices this is the only way to recover it from QDLoader state.

Comment: some collections https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224131/bootloop-issue-and-cant-go-to-recovery-mode#comment305555_224235