# Reboot loop for Moto Z2

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop

Recently my **moto z2 play** stuck in "*reboot loop*".

I couldn't able to move further due to "Developer option" was not enabled. I've tried the following methods, but no luck 0 still the restart is persistence

1. Tried "Restart Bootloader", and from PC done **fastboot** to wipe the User Data / Cache
2. Tried to enter "Recovery mode", no luck

Do we've any work around to get it fixed, as I don't want to waste the hardware resource

Comment: you have wiped userdata / cache from fastboot, does it mean your bootloader is unlocked?

Comment: for locked bootloader there is EDL mode. i have recently linked some collection, there are three *prog_emmc_firehose_8953_moto.mbn* you can try https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231754/any-way-to-root-a-crushed-phone-and-get-encryption-file-from-it#comment305554_231754

Comment: nothing much working