# How to install recovery image with fastboot? (Asus zenfone go 5.5 zb551kl)

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot, boot, stock-rom

I have an old phone **"Asus Zenfone go TV zb551kl"** and I am trying to fix it so I can give it to my nephew. It had a problem where the only thing that it can load is the **"fastboot"**. And, it says "Invalid boot image!!" whenever I boot recovery or normal boot. I just want to install the stock recovery image so I can re-install the stock ROM.

I'm just wondering if someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootloop issue and can't go to recovery mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224131/bootloop-issue-and-cant-go-to-recovery-mode)