# What can I do with an open source phone/kernel?

Tags: adb, root-access, bootloader, kernel, open-source

So this is my very first attempt in any kind of android development. I have [here](http://nokiaphones-opensource.azureedge.net/download/phones/Nokia5.4_V1.150.tar.bz2) my phone's official kernel source. I was wondering if I can build this to boot or if it's ready for building.

Also this phone is bootloader locked and there's no official or unofficial way to unlock it. So what can I do with the source or the boot image ?

Comment: source code is released to comply with GPL license only, it's useless on locked devices

Comment: I figure out this is the whole phone open source. I'm sure I can break into it and root/unlock it somehow

Comment: what if I can build it as singed image so I can flash it using the locked bootloader or even use EDL mode

Comment: doubt you can sign you don't have OEM keys. even EDL mode is impossible without OEM signed firehose programmer

Comment: I found stock rom/firmware ​for the phone and I think we can do a lot with a locked bootloader

Comment: start with edl.py good luck https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224131 https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226838

Comment: I found a less risky way using adb sideload but now I need a way to change active slot from B to A. Since the stock recovery is nonexistent, I couldn't get adb sideload funtion but now I found a specific boot entry just for adb sideload which is new and interesting. They have everything separated and insanely locked in some way. I'm updating here https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/source-code-up-stock-rom-up-time-to-find-root.4297799/